# Closed sets in $R^2$ with $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ and $B$ subsets of $X$. Define the distance $d(A,B)$ to be $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(p,q)\mid p\in A, q\in B\}$. Give an example of two closed subsets $A$ and $B$ of the euclidean plan $X=R^2$ for which $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $A=\{1,2,3..\}$, $B=\{n-\frac{1}{n}\}$. Both sets are closed with discrete topology inherited from the Euclidean space, but $d(A,B)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily verify that
$$A = \{(x, 0) : x \in \Bbb R\} \subset \Bbb R^2$$
(*i.e.* the $x$-axis) and
$$B = \left\{ \left(x, \frac{1}{x} \right) : x > 0 \right\} \subset \Bbb R^2$$
(*i.e.* the part of the graph of $y = 1/x$ to the right of the $y$-axis) satisfy the conditions you desire.